# how to specify that a method argument is a list of (e.g.) string

Tags: lisp, clos

In CLOS, how to specify that a method argument is  a list of (e.g.) strings?

e.g. something like:

```lisp
(defmethod m1 ((x (every 'string)))  
  (dolist (y x) (print (char y 0))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Methods can only be specialized on *classes*, not types. You could manually define the type `list-of-strings` with `deftype` and `satisfies`, but it would still be invalid to use it as a specializer in a `defmethod.`

From the [defmethod](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defmet.htm) entry of the CLHS:

> Only required parameters can be specialized. If parameter-specializer-name is a symbol it names a class.

Comment: Oh darn. I was hoping CLOS specializers worked like Python type hints. But your answer tells me that specializers are a far more restrictive language. I wonder why that is so? Runtime speed?

Comment: As far as I know, Python type hints have no effect at runtime, and are only used to statically determine if the code is "valid". This is completely orthogonal to OOP and runtime dispatch. If you want *some* kind of static hint, use `declare` and `declaim`, and see the "Type Specifier" section of the CLHS.

Comment: CLOS dispatch is a runtime mechanism. Doing arbitrary type checks at runtime is potentially very slow.

Comment: Another problem: CLOS classes are in a defined hierarchy. How would that work for types, where the computation of sub/supertype relationships would be difficult.

Comment: see also predicate dispatch / filtered dispatch